# MySQLi Query Returning Single Result -- Should Be Array of Results

Tags: php, mysql, class, mysqli, prepared-statement

Having some trouble with the following code. I've created a class to manage the DB connection, using what you see below as queryPreparedQuery and works fine when getting data for a single user, or any data that returns a single result using something like this...

```
include 'stuff/class_stuff.php';

function SweetStuff() {

    $foo = new db_connection();
    $foo->queryPreparedQuery("SELECT Bacon, Eggs, Coffee FROM Necessary_Items WHERE Available = ?",$bool);
    $bar = $foo->Load();
    $stuff = 'Brand of Pork is '.$bar['Bacon'].' combined with '.$bar['Eggs'].' eggs and '.$bar['Coffee'].' nectar for energy and heart failure.';

    return $stuff;

}

echo SweetStuff();
```

Problem is, I want to build the functionality in here to allow for a MySQL query which returns multiple results. What am I missing? I know it's staring me right in the face...

```
class db_connection
{
    private $conn;
    private $stmt;
    private $result;

    #Build a mysql connection
    public function __construct($host="HOST", $user="USER", $pass="PASS", $db="DB_NAME")
    {
        $this->conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo("Database connect Error : "
            . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
    #return the connected connection
    public function getConnect()
    {
        return $this->conn;
    }
    #execute a prepared query without selecting
    public function execPreparedQuery($query, $params_r)
    {
        $stmt =  $this->conn->stmt_init();
        if (!$stmt->prepare($query))
        {
            echo("Error in $statement when preparing: "
            . mysqli_error($this->conn));
            return 0;
        }
        $types = '';
        $values = '';
        $index = 0;
        if(!is_array($params_r))
        $params_r = array($params_r);
        $bindParam = '$stmt->bind_param("';
        foreach($params_r as $param)
        {

            if (is_numeric($param)) {
                $types.="i";
            }
            elseif (is_float($param)) {
                $types.="d";
            }else{
                $types.="s";
            }
            $values .=  '$params_r[' . $index . '],';
            $index++;
        }
        $values = rtrim($values, ',');
        $bindParam .= $types . '", ' . $values . ');';      

        if (strlen($types) > 0)
        {
            //for debug
            //if(strpos($query, "INSERT") > 0)
            //var_dump($params_r);
            eval($bindParam);
        }

        $stmt->execute();       
        return $stmt;
    }
    #execute a prepared query
    public function queryPreparedQuery($query, $params_r)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->execPreparedQuery($query, $params_r);
        $this->stmt->store_result();
        $meta = $this->stmt->result_metadata();
        $bindResult = '$this->stmt->bind_result(';
        while ($columnName = $meta->fetch_field()) {
            $bindResult .= '$this->result["'.$columnName->name.'"],';
        }
        $bindResult = rtrim($bindResult, ',') . ');';
        eval($bindResult);
    }
    #Load result
    public function Load(&$result = null)
    {       
        if (func_num_args() == 0)
        {
            $this->stmt->fetch();
            return $this->result;
        }
        else
        {
            $res = $this->stmt->fetch();
            $result = $this->result;
            return $res;
        }
    }

    #Load result
    public function Execute(&$result = null)
    {       
        if (func_num_args() == 0)
        {
            $this->stmt->fetch_array();
            return $this->result;
        }
        else
        {
            $res = $this->stmt->fetch_array();
            $result = $this->result;
            return $res;
        }
    }   

    private function bindParameters(&$obj, &$bind_params_r)
    {
        call_user_func_array(array($obj, "bind_param"), $bind_params_r);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Got this to work with Patrick's help. Was able to find the following code with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109517/mysqli-prepared-statement-to-return-nested-arrays), and with a few tweaks, it works beautifully. Added the following after the execute() statement in ExecPreparedQuery, returning an array at the very end instead of the single result:

```
    # these lines of code below return multi-dimentional/ nested array, similar to mysqli::fetch_all()
    $stmt->store_result();

    $variables = array();
    $data = array();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    while($field = $meta->fetch_field())
        $variables[] = &$data[$field->name]; // pass by reference

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $variables);

    $i=0;
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $array[$i] = array();
        foreach($data as $k=>$v)
            $array[$i][$k] = $v;
        $i++;
    }

    # close statement
    $stmt->close();

    return $array;
```

As a result of the altered code, I changed the call to interpret multidimensional array data rather than a single result, of course. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, I would recommend using a driver like Zend_Db.  Your use of eval scares the crap out of me.

Comment: You're right, it's not, but it was just a bogus example anyway so you get the idea. You're probably right about my use of eval... I'm pretty new to all this stuff. Any ideas as to returning multiple values? $this->stmt->fetch_all() as a replacement for $this->stmt->fetch() was presented as a solution but now I'm getting a fatal error (see Patrick's answer below).

Comment: @charleston82 instead of using eval, you should be able to do something like pushing all the values onto an array, then creating a string with the parameter types for the types then natively call `bind_param` and pass the two arguments you just created that way.

Comment: @Patrick I was able to find another question which referred to the answer you provided with code example, and got it to work. Updated code and link to the original question above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Execute` function you are calling `$this->stmt>fetch_array()`.

That function only returns an array of a single row of the result set.

You probably want:

`$this->stmt->fetch_all()`

**Update**

To retrieve the entire result set from a prepared statement:

`$this->stmt->store_result()`

Comment: Thanks Patrick! One step in the right direction, but now I'm getting: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all()

Comment: I missed the part that it's a prepared statement, I've updated the code to pull the entire result set from a PS.

Comment: Changed $this->stmt->fetch() to $this->stmt->store_result in Execute, and now getting a single empty result where should be 15 sets of data. Before was getting a good result, but only one.

Comment: Referring to Patrick's comment on the above question and updated code, thanks for your help & direction!!